# D3.js: How to select data from graph's brushed area?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following graph where mouse brush (light blue area) is used to select the data.
[image]

How can I get the data from the selected area?
The following and many other solutions I've tried does not seem to work.

```
brush.on('brush', function(d){  
    console.log(d);
});
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7tureLsf/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the brush's selected y axis extent using:

```
brush.on('brush', function(d){  
    k = brush.extent();
    console.log(k);
});
```

To get the data with in the selected brush area do:

```
k = brush.extent();
j = data.filter(function(d){
    return k[0] <= d.date && k[1] >=d.date;
});
console.log(j)//this is the selected dataset
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7tureLsf/4/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That console.log displays start and end time for selected brush area, but how can I get data objects that are within the selected brush area?

Comment: You can filter the data using the extent i have updated my answer also updated teh fiddle..output will come on teh console :)

Answer (score -1):

For `d3v4`, you can use this way :

```js
var selection = d3.event.selection;
var e = selection.map(x.invert, x); // return [start,end] for axis
```