# D3js v5 Trying to select multiple bars in bar chart using brush and saving values to variable and table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart code, wherein a user can select bars from a bar chart to populate a tabulated list. Since a lot of the data has values close to 0, it becomes difficult for users to click on those bars. In order to circumvent this issue, I made invisible bars which also hold the data, which have the height of the entire chart area. By using mouse over and click on these invisible bars I am able to let users highlight the bars and select them to populate a table list. The values also get saved to a object for further processing later. I was able to add zoom functionality as well.

Now the issue: I would like the user to be able to select multiple of these invisible bars and pass multiple values into the object. I have tried to use the brushX feature of d3js v4-v5 to let the user be able to highlight areas of interest for selection ([following this v3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009563/d3-js-how-to-select-data-from-graphs-brushed-area)). 
However, I cannot figure out how to get the values from the selected area. Currently it is returning empty arrays. 
Here is some of the code for the brush

```
var brush = d3.brushX();
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .style({
        "fill": "#69f",
        "fill-opacity": "0.3"
    });
brush.on('brush', function(d){  
    k = brush.extent();
    j = data.filter(function(d){
        return k[0] <= d.Name && k[1] >=d.Name;
    });
    console.log(j);
});
```

**Update:** Because plnkr is acting very weird I have made a block with the same code:
https://bl.ocks.org/Coola85/f20f66ee905d13880fc464d75b571603/

Here is the [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/C4s6go/) with the code for those who prefer plnkr.co

You must click Add Chart to see the Chart.

Please let me know if you need more information. 
Since I am new to D3js and SO, I would like to apologize for naivety.

Comment: Can I improve the question in any way to get some suggestions as to what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`brush.extent()` without argument](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_extent) now returns the function that calculates the extent, not the brush’s position. Use `d3.event.selection` instead.

Once you have the selected extent, compare it to your `x` scale:

```
brush.on('end', function(){
    var k = d3.event.selection; // extent of the brush, [x0, x1] since it's an x-brush

    var j = data.filter(function(d) {
        var x0 = x(d.ID), //  start of the corresponding band 
            x1 = x0 + x.bandwidth(); // end of the corresponding band 

        // check if the start of the brush is before the band 
        // and if the end of the brush is after the end of the band
        return k[0] <= x0 && k[1] >= x1;
    });

    console.log(j);
});
```